# MPMoviePlayerController Play Live Stream

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am making a Radio app for my website and I tried to use MPMoviePlayerController to access my streaming (.pls) file actually shoutcast but it doesn't work>

Any help or snippet to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommends you use HTTPLiveStreaming for audio/video streams. Do a little digging and I'm sure you could figure it out.

If it's a live stream, a playlist, or something like that, you can just use the API to create an m3u8 playlist that your MPMoviePlayerController can stream. Check out the docs and guides at the link below:

[HTTP Live Streaming Resources - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/)